# C# / WinForms: Failed to create component

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I made an user control in C#.
It compiles and runs just fine inside the debug window.

When I import the dll into a project and add it to a form this pops up:
[image: Error]

As the code is quite big and I have no idea where the problem is here is the whole project. https://github.com/MaticBabnik/CodeTab

Comment: The information you need is in the error message - **"The type codeTab.tab is not marked as serializable"**